# PHP cURL for large content with MIME Type

Tags: php, curl, httprequest, file-get-contents, php-curl

I am trying to get `MIME Type` and body as content using cURL. After checking on Google and Stackoverflow, i have got multiple code which make this operation successful done. But there is some confusion, choose the most reliable, speed and single **HTTP request code**.

1. Which code is best from these. or anyway we can make more better
2. I want a code which make single request to website `example.com`
3. Which code is good for getting large content from external website

**Code 1 :**

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url_curl) {
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // include headers in response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_curl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);   

    // Get the content type and content
    $response_curl = curl_exec($ch);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    $data_curl = substr($response_curl, $header_size);

    // Set the content type header (MIME Type)
    header('Content-Type:' . $content_type);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $data_curl;
}

//full page 

$homepage = file_get_contents_curl("https://example.com");
echo $homepage;
```

**Code 2 :**

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url_curl){
    $agent_curl = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_curl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent_curl);

    $data_curl = curl_exec($ch);
    $content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

    curl_close($ch);

    return compact('data_curl', 'content_type');
}

$data_webpage = file_get_contents_curl("https://example.com");
$homepage = $data_webpage['data_curl'];
$content_type = $data_webpage['content_type'];
header('Content-Type:'.$content_type);
echo $homepage;
```

**Code 3 :**

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    // Get the content type
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

    // Get the content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Set the content type header
    header('Content-Type:' . $content_type);

    return $data;
}

$homepage = file_get_contents_curl("https://example.com");
echo $homepage;
```

Code 4 :

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // Include response headers

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    // Get the content type from the response headers
    $content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);

    // Extract the data from the response (after the headers)
    $data = substr($response, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));

    curl_close($ch);

    // Set the content type header
    header('Content-Type:' . $content_type);

    return $data;
}

$homepage = file_get_contents_curl("https://example.com");
echo $homepage;
```

Comment: I suggest performing benchmarks to figure out which one is best.
Besides, the limiting factor is most likely not in the code, but in the stress of the server and the available bandwidth.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium how can i perform `Benchmark`. And which code out of 3 make single `HTTP Request`

Comment: From what I see, all three of them performs one request (`curl_exec`). As for benchmarking: Look at `https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettimeofday.php`. Place one call in front of your code under test and one after it. Substract the times and you've got the elapsed time. Repeat a few hundred thousand times and calculate the average. That's a (simple) benchmark.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Thanks for documents, i will check and try to test it. Between my friend said `Code 1` makes 2 HTTP request one to get Body and another to get HTTP.

Comment: I am not an expert on this matter, but AFAIK the header is ALWAYS part of the response (as specified by the HTTP standard). You can not 'opt out' of the headers being sent. However CURL usually 'hides' these headers from you, because you usually only care about the body (which follows the headers). I agree however that the first code is likely the least efficient.

Comment: The idea that a single CURL exec means one network request is, well, naive. A HTTPS request [looks more like this](https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:720/format:webp/0*WdxCooiriuTIrqzH.png). And after that the data itself is transferred in little packets over a layered protocol.

Comment: Do you have to post the entire 3 code snippets which look nearly identical? That might be helpful for testing but just posting the base code and then the 3 options might be more helpful to figure it out.